# undefined method `images_path' for #<#

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to handle image uploading for my rails app (rails 4.1).

The issue is I am getting this

> undefined method `images_path' for #<#

error every time try to go to /image/new.

I have checked my routes, my views, my controller, my model, and my uploader and everything seems fine. any advice or ideas?

Code:

**image_uploader.rb:**

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

storage :file

def store_dir
"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

end

**/models/image.rb:**

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

**Relevant Routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :image
```

image_controller.rb

```
class ImageController < ApplicationController


def new
  @image = Image.new(:image => params[:image_params])
end


def create
 @image = Image.create( image_params )

if @image.save
  redirect_to @image
else
  render 'new'
end    
end


def show
end

private


def image_params
 params.require(:image).permit(:title, :description, :image
end

def find_image
 @image = Image.find(params[:id])
end  
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-md-offset-2">
  <%= form_for @image, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field @image %>
    <p id="uploadClick">Click to Upload</p>

 <br>

    <%= submit_tag 'Upload Image', id: 'submitPhoto' %>

 <% end %>   
 </div>
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**SOLUTION:**

in new.html.erb I had to change:

```
<%= form_for @asset, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for :asset, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
```

my new action is now working correctly after those changes, hope this helps people in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `resources :image` to `resources :images` in `routes.rb` and change `new` and `create` methods in the controller like below

```
def new
  @image = Image.new
end

def create
  @image = Image.new(image_params)

  if @image.save
   redirect_to @image
  else
   render 'new'
  end    
end
```

Comment: No luck, not sure what is going on here. I had everything working with paperclip fine, Only reason I moved to CarrierWave is because I need to allow users to upload via a remote_url, paperclip does not seem to like IO.

Comment: This morning I stripped everything and restarted, with instead a model and table called Asset then added an Image:string onto it and am using that. But now instead of Image_path I am getting Asset_path error. Very strange.